# Xamarin button works on second click

Tags: c#, xamarin

i have a mobile application and once i press a button i want the border of the button to be changed. Which I managed to do however it works only if i click on the first button twice and then the rest works well. All button are identical just the name is different

here is the code for the button

```
protected void EnglishToCzech_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button englishToCzech = (Button)sender;
            if (englishToCzech.BorderColor.Equals(Color.Default))
            {
                englishToCzech.BorderColor = Color.FromHex("#da2c43");
                czechToEnglish.BorderColor = Color.Default;
                english.BorderColor = Color.Default;

            }
            else
                englishToCzech.BorderColor = Color.Default;

        }
```

and here is the xaml

```
<Button x:Name="englishToCzech" Grid.Column="2" Text="{ grial:Translate A_ButtonEnglishToCzech}"  Style="{ StaticResource CircleActionButtonFlatStyle }"   FontSize="14"  WidthRequest="50" HeightRequest="50" CornerRadius="30"   BorderWidth="2" Clicked="EnglishToCzech_Clicked"/>
```

Is there a way to set it in code how many times user have to pres the button in order for it work at the first click?

Comment: well it's obvious ... `englishToCzech.BorderColor` is not `Color.Default` at first click ... use MVVM patern and binding so you can keep state in VM not in UI

Comment: What button doesn't get the `BorderColor` you expect on the first click? There are three different buttons in your example and your requirements are a bit unclear.

Comment: post your entire xaml

Comment: Hi , you can use `breakpoint` or  `Console.WriteLine("---")` to check whether method be invoked .

Answer (score 0):

Debug your code. Put a breakpoint in `EnglishToCzech_Clicked` and ensure that you are getting in this method on each click. During the first execution, hover over `englishToCzech.BorderColor` and see what the value is. Likely, the BorderColor isn't Color.Default so it gets set to Color.Default. This is why it works the second time.